# Apache conf with Passenger and ProxyPassMatch regex for multiple Ruby on Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, apache, passenger, proxypass

I have an Apache Sling app being served by Apache. However, when someone goes to the same url but has /mstarfb at the front of the url they get served by a Ruby on Rails app via Passenger. I would like to add a second Ruby on Rails app served by /i-metaphor.

Here's what I currently have and works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName beta.example.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

PassengerEnabled off

ProxyPassMatch ^/(?!mstarfb)(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8890/$1   
ProxyPassReverse / http://beta.example.com:8890


DocumentRoot /home/ruby/webapps/m-star-fb/current/public
    <Directory "/home/ruby/webapps/m-star-fb/current/public">
        PassengerEnabled on
        RailsBaseURI /mstarfb
        # This relaxes Apache security settings.
        AllowOverride all
        # MultiViews must be turned off.
        Options -MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

The first question is how the regex should look. I've tried various combinations that I could think of but I'm not sure if they were failing because the regex was wrong or if because the rest of my config was wrong. Somtehing like:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(?!mstarfb|?!i-metaphor)(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8890/$1
```

The second question is how do I organize the virtual host? After the Proxy lines I've tried:

```
    DocumentRoot /home/ruby/webapps
    <Directory "/home/ruby/webapps/m-star-fb/current/public">
    PassengerEnabled on
    RailsBaseURI /mstarfb
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

But it breaks my first app... I haven't tried adding the second app yet.